It suggests vs It would suggest

In an answer of my question. The person who answered my question used "suggest"and "would suggest".
I don't know what the difference between them.
Does "would suggest" sound less certain than "suggest"?

Does this answer your question? How does "would" work in "I would agree"?

Please don't post screenshots of text; cut and paste. It makes it much easier to search, and for people with accessibility issues.

The original form that was asked about was "I'll make", and the person who responded said that I'll make suggests...
But the person who responded goes on to address something not actually asked about, the "I'm making" form, and so there is an implicit "counterfactual" condition: you asked about someone who says "I'll make" but let me tell you also about what it would mean if someone said "I'm making", as it will shed more light on the topic.
We can make that condition explicit:

On the other hand, if the speaker were to say  "I'm making...", that would suggest...

or

Supposing the speaker said "I'm making...". That would suggest...

Native speakers make such appropriate choices without giving them much conscious thought. It's like speech "muscle memory" so to speak.

Yes, prefixing "suggest" with "would" generally makes the remark sound less definite (perhaps in a bid to not be presumptuous about the surrounding context) and, thereby, less commital.
In your example, choosing "would suggest" over "suggests" conveys that the utterance I'm making you a cup of tea is being a hypothetical alternative (specifically: being counterfactual) to the actual utterance I'll make you a nice cup of tea.
Sometimes, "would" is added to "suggest" just as a filler, to sound less direct, when wanting to be polite or less forceful.
So, from least to most emphatic:

it would suggest
it suggests
it does suggest.


These assertions can be similarly ranked:

it would seem
it seems
it does seem

i would think
i think
i do think

i would agree
i agree
i do agree.



There is no distinction being made between "suggests" and "would suggest" here.
What was actually written in the quoted text at the very start was "I'll make (you) a nice cup of tea". What this quote suggests is various subtle things about the situation (that someone has just decided to do something). Because "I will X" is in the future tense, X has not started yet.
The responder is contrasting this with another construction, "I'm making you a nice cup of tea". This suggests various, slightly different, subtle things about the situation (that someone is already in the process of doing something) because "I am X" is in the present continuous.
So why has the person written "would suggest" in the second case? Because their proposed change was not what was written in the quote. It's a hypothetical, a conditional, a "what might have been". Compare it to this sentence:

I see you are wearing gloves. That suggests it is cold. If you had been wearing a sun-hat, that would suggest it was warm.

